# SQL Server stored procedure based on input parameters value

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
create procedure sp1
(
    @p1 int = null
)
as
begin
    select f1, f2, f3 
    from table1;
end
```

How to add the "where" clause to the select query (where f1=@p1) only when @p1 is not null? if @p1 is null then return all rows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create procedure dbo.sp1
(
    @p1 int = null
)
as
begin
select f1, f2, f3 
from dbo.table1 where(@p1 is not null and f1=@p1)
end
```

OR

You can Use

Here Query Returns all rows if `@p1` is null (Because @p1 return `true` when `NULL`)

```
  create procedure dbo.sp1
(
    @p1 int = null
)
as
begin
select f1, f2, f3 
from dbo.table1 where(@p1 is null OR f1=@p1)
end
```

Comment: @Jalil You can use 2nd one

Comment: @Jalil Then you should've made that requirement explicitly in your question

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The `where clause` will work only when `@p1 is not null`

```
SELECT f1,
       f2,
       f3
FROM   dbo.table1
WHERE  @p1 IS NOT NULL
       AND f1 = @p1
```

If you want to return all the values if @p1 is null then just a `ISNULL` function. If @p1 is `Not Null` then `f1=@p1` values will be returned else all the values will be returned. Try this

```
SELECT f1,
       f2,
       f3
FROM   dbo.table1
WHERE  f1 = isnull(@p1,f1)
```

Comment: Maybe not for the code to run, but it makes it a little easier to understand what your intentions are.

Answer (score 1):

In case @p1 is null, below will return every thing and if there is a value, it will apply the condition.

```
 WHERE @p1 is NULL OR f1=@p1
```